# Force generics implements property in TypeScript (constrains on generics)

Tags: generics, typescript

I want to force that generic implements property in TypeScript.
My current code is:

```
interface IEventHandler<TArgs>
{
    (args: TArgs): void
}


interface ISubscribable<THandlerType>
{ 
    bind(fn: THandlerType): void;

    unbind(fn: THandlerType): void;
}

interface IEvent<TArgs> extends ISubscribable<IEventHandler<TArgs>>
{
}
```

Something like `interface IEventHandler<TArgs> where TArgs : has_property_sender`. I know where does not exists for TypeScript, so maybe I can get a workaround with another interface?

Is this possible in TypeScript?

**Edited:**
[Code if it helps someone else](https://jsfiddle.net/g51whL6n/2/). I don't know if it can be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) (section "Generic Constraints") in Typescript, e.g.:

```
interface has_property_sender {
    sender: Object;
}

interface MyArgs extends has_property_sender {
    property: Object;
}

interface IEventHandler<TArgs extends has_property_sender>
{
    (args: TArgs): void
}
```

Comment: Thanks.   
I manage to do it after few hours, with your answer that extends is the correct way (this is my third day on TypeScript). I already tried your approach but could get sender to be of type generics.  
If you have the time, could you please look with one eye at the bottom of my code if it could be optimised. There is comment with a few question marks.

Comment: @Makla - I've checked your code and haven't found a way "to remove Edit" for now...